# React/JavaScript - Validate two or more inputs

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, validation, state

Is it possible to validate two or more inputs in the same file ? As I am trying to create a second validator for another input. I have one validator for a number input -

```
function FormVal() {
  const [phone, setPhone] = React.useState<string>();
  const [errors, setErrors] = React.useState<{ phone: string }>();

  const handleChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const {
      target: { value }
    } = event;
    setErrors({ phone: '' });
    setPhone(value);
    let reg = new RegExp(/^\d*$/).test(value);

    if (!reg) {
      setErrors({ phone: 'Only numbers' });
    }
  };
}
```

I would like to create second input like email or text but I don't want to create a new file and I was wondering how can I add another validator there.

Comment: This is not going to answer the question directly, but I do believe it to be bad design to include phone number and email validation together. They have little cohesion and they are not likely to change for the same reason, hence they have different responsibilities. They should probably be separated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the above-mentioned approach, What you can do is create a schema to validate the inputs. There are many great libraries for this.

In a large project writing a validator for each type of input can be a complex task. You can use [fastest-validator](https://github.com/icebob/fastest-validator) which is the fastest data validation library for javascript.